# why does my selectlist not display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi fellow programmers,

At the moment I am trying to make a dynamic tablerow that the user can fill in, with input fields and a selectlist (so the user can only select these options to fill in for that td-cell). The input fields work like they should, but somehow my selectlist inside the td doesn't get displayed at all. I checked the console and there is no errors.. here is my code:

```
//2 lists to loop through and get the right classname for the inputfields (for later use)
var camera_idcolumns = ['idkolom','merkkolom','typekolom','modelkolom','ipkolom','mackolom','usernamekolom','passwordkolom','bijzonderhedenkolom'];
var camera_idvelden = ['idveld','merkveld','typeveld','modelveld','ipveld','macveld','usernameveld','passwordveld','bijzonderhedenveld'];


rijToevoegen(camera_idcolumns, camera_idvelden, "camera");

//the function that adds the dynamic row to be filled in by the user.
 function rijToevoegen(columnarray, fieldarray, tabelnaam){
    var columns = columnarray;
    var fields = fieldarray;
    var row = '<tr>';
    for(i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
        if(i==0){
            continue;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            var lijstnaam = "testlijst";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../logic/getlijst.php",
                data: {lijstnaam: lijstnaam},
                success: function(data) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(data);
                    row += "<td class="+columns[i]+"><select id='selectlijst'>";
                    for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                        row += "<option value="+response[i]['itemnaam']+">"+response[i]['itemnaam']+"</option>";
                    }
                    row += "</select></td>";
                }
            });
            continue;
        } else{
            row += "<td class="+columns[i]+"><input type='text' id="+fields[i]+"></td>";
        }
    }
    row += '</tr>';
    $(tabelnaam).append(row);

}
```

The response from the AJAX-call is an arraylist with the items the selectlist should contain. It feels like i did everything right, but it still won't display in the browser at all (also not while inspecting it in the elements of the browser).

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet:

```
row += '</tr>';
$(tabelnaam).append(row);
```

is running before your ajax call completes and actually runs the code which populates that variable. If that code relies on the result of the (async, don't forget) ajax call, then move it into the "success" function.

Comment: oh god I think you're completely right.. Is it possible to continue the loop only if the ajax-call has finished? I know complete: function() { continue; } breaks the code, so how would I fix this?

Comment: No you can't. The loop is in one thread and the ajax is in another thread. You'd have to copy this little bit of code into your final "else" as well, i think, unfortunately. OR, you re-architect it without a loop, and just kick off the next stage of the process from within your "success" function.

Comment: I will see what I will do, a tremendous thank you for helping me and explaining so clearly! cheers :)